# realloc in function is filling up memory, but is runing fine main()

Tags: c

When I try and realloc by func call, my memory fills up real quick, but when i am doing it in main() it's fine.

Can you tell me why this is. Thank you much.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char qp[500];
} xy;

void fl(xy **ptr, int k)
{
    int i;
    xy *p=NULL;

    p=(xy*)realloc(p,k*sizeof(xy));
    if(p!=NULL)
        *ptr=p;
    else
        system("pause");
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fd;
    char tmp[500];
    int n,z,h;

    xy *p=NULL,*ptr;

    p=(xy*)malloc(sizeof(xy));
    fd=fopen("files\\dirfl_id.txt","r");
    n=0;
    while(!feof(fd)) {
        fflush(stdin);
        fscanf(fd,"%d\t%[^\n]s",&h,tmp);
        if(feof(fd))
            break;
        n++;
        fl(&p,n);
        strcpy(p[n-1].qp,tmp);
        printf("\n%d,%s",n-1,p[n-1].qp);
    }

    printf("\n\n%s",p[0].qp);
}
```

When I try running the same code but not using a function call, it will load fine. the file i am loading is about 1mb big and so it should not be a problem. But still it will crash my system.

Comment: remove `p=(xy*)malloc(sizeof(xy));` at main. `p=(xy*)realloc(p,k*sizeof(xy));` --> `p=(xy*)realloc(*ptr,k*sizeof(xy));` at f1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xy *p=NULL;
// ...
p = realloc(p, newsize);
```

`realloc(NULL, size)` have same effect as `malloc`. You wanted first line to be `xy *p=*ptr;`, then actual reallocation would happen.